# Trying to use the data the user entered in JOptionPane after it was looped

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with a task we have to do and I came here for help. They asked me to ask the user to enter their name and surname in one JOptionPane.showInputDialog so I did here:

String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name And Surname Here");

After that they wanted the user to enter the distance they achieved over 3 days in 3 JOptionPanes but they wanted it to be in a loop, and so I did that as seen here:

```
int i;
int Day = 0;    
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)   
{
Day = (int) Double.parseDouble
(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Distance " + i + " Here (km): "));
}
```

Then after that, the problem starts because I don't know how to use the data that the user entered. I tried all kinds of things but now I'm just sitting with this code in front of me and it's quite a train smash.

```
double day1 = 0;
double day2 = 0;
double day3 = 0;
double total = day1 + day2 + day3;
double average = total / 3;

System.out.println(name + ":");
System.out.println("Day 1: " + day1);
System.out.println("Day 2: " + day2);
System.out.println("Day 3: " + day3);
System.out.println("That is a total of " + total + 
"km, giving an average of " + average + "km per day.");
```

If this is still confusing I'll attach the questions they asked, any kind of help will be appreciated!

Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Since `Day` is only a single number, each value only lasts as long as the loop does. After the loop runs 3 times, you will only have the last value. You no longer have the first two values. One way to solve your problem is to process each value as they are entered inside the loop. For example, you can print the message out immediately with that value. You can also add it to a total so that you can print out the total and average after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

One of several possible solutions would be to use an array of integers. In your input loop you could then read every value into the array so that all values are available later.

For Example:

```
// int array of 3 integers
int[] day = new int[3];
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    // array index 0 to 2, so use i - 1 for array access
    day[i - 1] = (int) Double.parseDouble
    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Distance " + i + " Here (km): "));
}
```

Then you could, for example, assign these values to your `day1, day2, day3` variables.

```
double day1 = day[0];
double day2 = day[1];
double day3 = day[2];
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I asked my teacher and I found the solution to my problem, I had to put both my question and output in the loop so I could loop 3 times so as the question asked of me. I once again apologize if my question was unclear or disorganized, it was my first time posting something here. I also apologize if someone finds this and find this unhelpful, I'll be posting the solution later on when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses and feedback, this is the solution I got to and now the program can be used to log kilometers walked, ran, cycled, or swam for 3 days. It was an assignment I had to complete it's not the hardest but I'm still new in this whole thing.

```
    String name =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    ("Enter Name And Surname Here: ");
    
    System.out.println(name + ":");
    
    double total = 0;
    
    double km;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        km = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("Enter Distance of Day " + i ));
        System.out.println("Day " + i + ": " + km);
        total += km;
    }
    
    System.out.println("That gives a total of " + total
            + "km, giving an average of " + ( total / 3) + "km per day.");
    
       
}
```

}

If someone has something similar I hope this helps!~

Thank you